# How to display post and custom post type count by published by author in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

I need to display the total post count published by the author this code is displayed the total number of post

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGq4t.png)

Please Check both the code and screenshot and give me a solution on how can I display the total number of posts by the author.

```
// Post Type - Post
function postcode( $atts )
 
{
    return (count_user_posts(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'post') );
}
 
add_shortcode( 'codepost', 'postcode');
```

```
// Custom Post Type
function tourcode( $atts )
 
{
    return (count_user_posts(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'tourism') );
}
 
add_shortcode( 'codetour', 'tourcode');
```

Comment: What the code for `count_user_posts` function

Answer (score 0):

Easy just put all the `post_types` into an `array` like below:

```
// All post types
function my_get_author_post_count( $atts )
 
{
    return count_user_posts(get_the_author_meta('ID'), ['post', 'tourism']);
}
 
add_shortcode( 'get_author_post_count', 'my_get_author_post_count');
```